# Some doubts on Simpsons Rule by the Method of Undetermined Coefficients

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, simpsons-rule

There is this note about Quadratic Interpolation by Simpsons Rule that I don't quite understand how to get the LHS.

Simpsons Rule by the Method of Undetermined Coefficients

We seek an approximation
$$I\approx A_0f(-h)+A_1 f(0)+A_2 f(h)$$

Indeed, one expects the coefficients to be proportional to the length of the interval, but not to change if the $x$-variable is simply translated. So it is reasonable to guess that $A_i=ha_i$ gives true constants $a_i$. Anyway, this will be confirmed in the calculation.

Exactness for quadratics means exactness for $f(x)=1,x,x^2$ and inserting each of these in turn gives
$$2h=h(a_0+a_1+a_2)$$
$$0=h^2(-a_0+a_2)$$
$$\frac{2}{3}h^3=h^3(a_0+a_2)$$

The solution is $a_0=a_2=1/3, a_1=1/4$.

My questions are:
1. Why is the coefficients are proportional to the length of the interval?
2. How do they get the LHS: $2h,0,\frac{2}{3}h^3$?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please correct $a_1=2-2a_0=2-2/3=4/3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1:

Letting
$x = hy$,
so
$dx = h dy$,
$\int_{-h}^h f(x) dx
=\int_{-1}^1 f(hy) hdy
=h\int_{-1}^1 f(hy) dy
$.

For 2:

$\int_{-h}^h x^k dx
=\dfrac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}\big|_{-h}^h
=\dfrac{h^{k+1}-(-h)^{k+1}}{k+1}
=(2h, 0, (2h^3)/3, 0)
\text{ for } k=(0, 1, 2, 3)
$.

Correspondingly,

$\begin{array}\\
a_0(-h)^k+a_0(0^k)+a_2h^k
&=a_0+a_1+a_2 \text{ for } k=0,\\
&=-a_0h+a_2h =h(a_2-a_0)\text{ for } k=1,\\
&=a_0h^2+a_2h^2
=h^2(a_0+a_2) \text{ for } k=2,\\
\end{array}
$

But these need to be
multiplied by
$h$
as shown in the answer to 1.